# Clearing form fields after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an email form on my website. Nothing fancy, it just sends an email to my inbox.

The thing is, this week I've had 2 people email me and both have sent 7-15 emails all exactly identical. Turns out, the form doesn't clear when you submit it...

Here's the code for the post:

```
$("#contact-submit").click(function() {
    if (validateForm()) {       
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/includes/contact.php',
            data: { name: $('#contact-name').val(),
                    from: $('#contact-email').val(),
                    subject: $('#contact-subject').val(),
                    message: $('#contact-message').val()
            }, // end data
            success: function clearFields() {
                $('#contact-name').val('');
                $('#contact-email').val('');
                $('#contact-subject').val('');
                $('#contact-message').val('');
                $('.errmsg').text('Your email was sent successfully.');
                $('.errmsg').css('color', '#389320');
            } // end success
        }); // end ajax
    }
    else
    {
        var errmsg = "Your email could not be sent.<br />";
        errmsg += "Please ensure that you've filled in all the fields.";
        $(".errmsg").html(errmsg);
        $(".errmsg").css("color", "#ff0000");
    }
}); // end click
function validateForm() {
    var contact_name = $("#contact-name");
    var contact_email = $("#contact-email");
    var contact_subject = $("#contact-subject");
    var contact_message = $("#contact-message");
    var result = true;

    console.log("contact name" + contact_name.val());

    if (contact_name.val() == "")
    {
        result = false;
    }
    if (contact_email.val() == "")
    {
        result = false;
    }
    if (contact_subject.val() == "")
    {
        result = false;
    }
    if (contact_message.val() == "")
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Odd thing is I've seen this work in the past, so I can't understand why its not clearing the fields. Looking at the code, I wonder if the `// end data` comment isn't interfering in some way...

It's worth noting that I get an HTTP 500 on the contact.php page for each submission so it also seems possible that the post isn't going through 100%... Not sure what I should do about that.

If anyone can provide some insight here, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Probably

```
  success: function clearFields() {
```

needs to be replaced with

```
  success: function(success_record) {
```

Note : `//End data` isn't interfering for sure.

Comment: can you explain more about the success action you're suggesting? I don't understand...

Comment: Reviewed your entire code. nothing seemed to be improper except that particular line "success". I have been using it since a long time. The success_record is nothing but the callback appearing from the controller. You can pass through the controller a flag. Check fla here in success_record.flag and if true, clear all fields.

Comment: so success_record is a flag you set?

Comment: No. Thats the callback you will recieve from your controller and it will be available in success_record. try consoling it.